# Qu’est-ce que « Passe-Partout » veut dire ici ?

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

Voici un extrait de la chanson [les étoiles filantes](http://www.parolesmania.com/paroles_cowboys_fringants_les_9923/paroles_les_etoiles_filantes_342427.html) des « Cowboys fringants » auquel cette question se rapporte.

> Ces hivers enneigés,
>       A construire des igloos,
>       Et rentrer les pieds g'lés
>       Juste à temps pour Passe-Partout

Qu’est-ce qui passe-partout veut dire ici ? Selon le Wiktionnaire, le mot peut désigner [plusieurs objets](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passe-partout). Il me paraît qu’aucun bidule de l’ensemble que l’on y fournit ne peut avoir quelque chose à voir avec la chanson.

**Mes tentatives de comprendre ce mot**

Les majuscules tapent dans l’œil, et je trouve ça également surprenant que l’article manque. Il s’agit donc vraisemblablement d’un nom. La partie « juste à temps pour » sous-entend que « Passe- Partout » se produit à un temps donné du jour. Bref, je me doute d’un divertissement dont on s’occupe au temps de l’hiver.

Étrangement, le Wiktionnaire n’en a rien dit, et il est dur de trouver quelque chose d’éclaircissant sur la toile : la plupart des résultats de Google n’est pas à propos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pour comprendre il faut savoir que le groupe [*Les Cowboys fringants*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Cowboys_fringants) est un groupe québécois.

Passe-Partout est ici un nom propre. Le premier personnage qui se soit nommé Passe-Partout est, je crois, celui de Jules Verne dans [*Le Tour du monde en quatre-vingts jours*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Tour_du_monde_en_quatre-vingts_jours). Dans la chanson que tu cites il s'agit du personnage de Passe-Partout, un des personnages de l'émission enfantine éponyme québécoise [Passe-Partout](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passe-Partout_%28%C3%A9mission_de_t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vision%29)<sup>*</sup>. L'article de wikipédia nous dit que le nom a été choisi pour rester proche de celui de l'émission étasunienne qui l'a inspirée : *Sesame Street*. Donc si on veut se référer à un des sens du nom commun *passe-partout* il s'agit de la clé qui ouvre toutes les portes.  Le passe-partout, comme le mot magique « sésame »,  symbolise l'ouverture culturelle sur le monde que veut représenter cette émission.

Dans la chanson en question, [Les Étoiles Filantes](http://www.parolesmania.com/paroles_cowboys_fringants_les_9923/paroles_les_etoiles_filantes_342427.html), le personnage qui s'exprime est un trentenaire qui se remémore des (bons) souvenirs d'enfance, l'école, les jeux de billes... et les jeux dans la neige l'hiver (on est au Québec !) qui s'arrêtaient juste à temps pour rentrer à la maison voir l'émission.

* <sup>D'autres personnages de l'émission sont Passe-Carreau et Passe-Montagne.</sup>